# issue of installing chromadb library in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-prompt, libraries, install.packages

I am trying to install **chromadb** library using pip but it is showing errors I also installed Microsoft visual studio build tools but I am not able to install it. It is showing error as

```
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.37.32822\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1120
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib
Failed to build chroma-hnswlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for chroma-hnswlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I am trying to install the **chromadb** library so that I can import it to python for my project but I can't install it.